# Change LaunchScreen storyboard ThemeMode based on user preferences

Tags: swift, swiftui

is there a way of changing the LaunchScreen theme mode based on user preferences?

Currently, I allow the user to set the theme mode of the app (system, light or dark)

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @AppStorage("themeMode") var themeMode: String = ThemeMode.system.rawValue

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                ApplicationView()
                    .preferredColorScheme(ThemeMode.fromString(themeMode).colorScheme)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if the user selects light mode and the system is dark, the launchscreen is dark, the same with light mode

I'd like to be able to set the launchscreen to light mode if the preferences are light mode

After the launchscreen everything works perfectly btw

Comment: How did you configure your Launchscreen? In your example the `preferredColorScheme` is applied only to your View itself. As far as I know Launchscreens are static and cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: It's just the LaunchScreen storyboard, the image/backrgound has the dynamic color/image that uses the Any/Dark appearance to switch
So no more logic

But i'd like to be able to set light mode if the app is set to light mode for the launchscreen, it seems to take system deafults